# Calculate difference between two dates and group and count the results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

If I have a table with field `date_completed`. I would like to calculate the difference between this date and the time now in months

```
(date_completed.year * 12) + date_completed.month - (Date.today.year * 12) + Date.today.month
```

and then group the results based on the number of months e.g.

```
No Months => Count
1         =>  10
2         =>   5
3         =>   6
```

etc.

Is it possible to calculate the difference between two dates in a database and then group and count the results?

Comment: what have you try? do you want rails or sql ? show us sample data and desire result.

Comment: What is the data type of `date_completed` field?

Comment: date_completed is a date field

Comment: I tried doing it in rails but couldn't do the counting of the group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Postgre-SQL specific SQL query will be something like below - it makes use of `extract` and `age` method of PostgreSQL(Refer [Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html))

```
select extract(year from age(date_completed)) * 12 + 
         extract(month from age(date_completed)) as months, 
       count(*) from learn group by months;
```

Sample output:

```
"months"|"count"
       2|     2 
       3|     1
       4|     1
```

I made use of a table `learn` above, you need to change it to table name you have.